# Set checked state on a listview with a CursorAdapter (CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListFragment` containing a multiple choice `ListView`. If I set the layout in my `CursorAdapter` to `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice`, I will be able to see the checked items in my `ListView`. But I want to use a custom layout and change the background color when the item is checked. It seemed rather simple but I couldn't find the answer to my problem. I thought about setting the color in the bindView of my adapter but I'm not sure it's where it belongs, since my adapter doesn't know which items are checked. So I tried to use a selector and apply it on the background of my textview like the following :

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
          android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
          android:padding="6dp"
          android:background="@drawable/list_selector"/>
```

**list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_pressed" />

    <!-- Selected -->
    <item android:state_selected="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_active" />

    <!-- Checked -->
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/list_active" />

    <!-- Normal -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_normal" />
</selector>
```

The pressed state is working but not the checked one. I wonder if my TextView is even checked at all. But if it's not, how does the `ListView` keep track of the checked items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for [android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_multiple_choice.xml) uses a `CheckedTextView`, so you are on the right path. Just change the `TextView` in your layout to a `CheckedTextView`.